# AWS API Gateway - applying basic authentication to some URL patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to secure a URL pattern (GET to `/swagger-ui/open_api.yml`) in API Gateway with Basic Authentication. No other URLs should require it.

To implement that, I added a Lambda authorizer which returns `Allow`/`Deny` policy for all requests containing `swagger-ui` in request path checking `Authorization` header. This secures the API definition.

But now API Gateway wants a basic authentication header for all URLs (e.g., POST to `/runApi`) and returns `401 Unauthorized` if it's not set... Is there a way to override this behavior, so that basic authentication is only set for [Swagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_(software))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS API Gateway, we can define authorizer per route i.e. HTTP Method + CPU pattern.

So, in this case you can define a lambda authorizer for Basic authentication for your specific URL pattern GET /swagger-ui/open_api.yml or ANY /swagger-ui/{proxy+}. The latter pattern catches all sub paths under /swagger-ui for any HTTP method.

For rest all URLs, if you don't require any authorization, you can apply the catch-all proxy pattern /{proxy+} with an integration defined for backend APIs. Here, you won't apply any authorizer and API gateway will pass on requests to your backend integration endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, Abhishek - this worked like a charm! My confusion was due to the entire app deployed as a single lambda function with all requests mapped to it. Splitting it up into two resources makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Re *"For rest all URLs"*: Do you mean *"For the rest of the URLs"*? Or something with [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76235509/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).